# recaptcha wasn't solving by anticaptcha plugin in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy, selenium-chromedriver, recaptcha

I've recently started using selenium for a project I've been working on for a while that involves automation. One of the roadblocks in the plan was the ReCaptcha system, so I decided to use anti-captcha as the service that would solve the captchas when my bot encountered it. I properly installed the plugin and found some test code with selenium on their site.

```
from python_anticaptcha import AnticaptchaClient, NoCaptchaTaskProxylessTask

def captcha_solver():
    api_key = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    site_key = '6LdZPw8aAAAAAA_1XrIfloCojPwo4TdJ_A_7ioRy'  # grab from site
    url = 'https://www.rp.gob.pa/'
    
    client = AnticaptchaClient(api_key)
    task = NoCaptchaTaskProxylessTask(url, site_key)
    job = client.createTask(task)
    job.join()
    return job.get_solution_response()

captcha = captcha_solver()
driver.execute_script('document.getElementById("g-recaptcha-response").innerHTML = "{}";'.format(captcha))
time.sleep(1)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//button[@type="submit"]'))).click()
```

the anticaptcha says the recaptcha is solved, the solved code comes like this

```
03AGdBq24C2SwOzrdAoGpltxX-8vMuBEjwSmHVIRkVcthtqHEsmm7sEyac1vUgTZQHs7bUtK0YwW6NiduvAmXQt6xVxGRSvO1XhsiRPTfa8spSxRG6scwInLccriAV408I4plNzEykQVQya9v2u4PMyCyrVQ6NADI_A_56DuQvuzhLKuiNL-eN4MvtwEt1ueDefa3nwHUZoW-hgMiEcg1jQ4UhZJ0Ncz1favKF8aMB--Ru1-ewClN41MjyVwREHn1xuCNtnMt5rxaFLt0f5SehaFkdccem1rbCTqsb7lOomTEWpX0TiWKl2kOP9efgOJDlwV84ISncydrQseda7pTlf6nL0m_oUY8U-tnWFQi2i8g_ZWwOgrXb6o9lBapoy0-z0SWZARHKecBbfwHa906mG_b2jh9-IPOI-6rduxTnDw4HDlizXGKOU7Z8Cb8pQAhiaYEejiaBU0X2Dc44dq7CL4Q_365277zoKG4YDwgRXjUstT39e-3C_-lpjdNHMkkz9RJTNe0kOie2i3U-BruAh3trh-vM8F7JU4f8m52F335q3GdUb8FQXL7Fd9hLJpb9KfDMV0pfmRuxl5NoECKRbP2gtTTXUJ0ZwQ
```

I execute this solved code to `g-recaptcha-response` textarea and says the selenium to click the button, but the result is this
[image: Result]

I cannot solve the recaptcha using anticaptcha, I don't whether my code has a problem, but I followed the official documentation to use the recaptcha. Guys please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've finally managed to resolve this myself. In case anyone else is struggling with a similar issue, here was my solution:

- Open the console and execute the following `cmd: ___grecaptcha_cfg.clients`
- Find the path which has the callback function, in my case it's ___grecaptcha_cfg.clients[0].R.R
- Use the following code: `driver.execute_script(f"___grecaptcha_cfg.clients[0].R.R.callback('{new_token}')")` (Remember to change the path accordingly)

Can get the path using the google console
[image: ___grecaptcha_cfg.clients]

Right click the callback -> copy property path and paste in `driver.execute_script` and add this on start `___grecaptcha_cfg.` and pass the solved token value

This [Article](https://discourse.openbullet.dev/t/guide-recaptcha-v2-bypass-and-callbacks/3252) will help you to find the ___grecaptcha_cfg.clients of your recaptcha site

```
driver.execute_script('document.getElementById("g-recaptcha-response").innerHTML = "{}";'.format(g_response))   
time.sleep(1)  
driver.execute_script(f"___grecaptcha_cfg.clients[0].R.R.callback('{g_response}')")
```

Comment: Me personally use the Anticapthca plugin which is their official tool https://antcpt.com. Good thing about it is that it runs callback method for you when captcha solved, because the selector you have found (__grecaptcha_cfg.clients[0].R.R.callback) changes from time to time when Google updates Recaptcha.