# How to send POST request for solving captcha Python

Tags: python

Good hour
I am not familiar with using post requests in python to solve such problems. I will write down the details below, please explain what data needs to be transmitted in the post request, also please write the code of this request
The essence is as follows: during the password change from the account in the rambler mail, you need to enter a captcha. The captcha solution was made through the service, receiving a solution token in response, but I have no idea how to send it. Everything works on python + selenium + requests
The captcha block is in the following form`

```
<iframe src="https://newassets.hcaptcha.com/captcha/v1/9f58d19/static/hcaptcha-checkbox.html#id=1sruemy18uwp&amp;host=id.rambler.ru&amp;sentry=true&amp;reportapi=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.hcaptcha.com&amp;recaptchacompat=off&amp;custom=false&amp;hl=ru&amp;tplinks=on&amp;sitekey=322e5e22-3542-4638-b621-fa06db098460&amp;theme=light" title="widget containing checkbox for hCaptcha security challenge" tabindex="0" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" data-hcaptcha-widget-id="1sruemy18uwp" data-hcaptcha-response="" style="width: 303px; height: 78px; overflow: hidden;">
#document
</iframe>
<textarea id="h-captcha-response-1sruemy18uwp" name="h-captcha-response" style="display: none;"></textarea>
```

When solving a captcha by tracking events in developer tools (using Google chrome), 1 post request occurs:

```
Headers => General

Request URL: https://hcaptcha.com/checkcaptcha/E0_eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJkYXRhIjoiUFBvbU0vUXJjVVpOenlHOENvSVlpOEVCK2RwSElDU1IrVlk5V1QxNXRTU3RwRWtkcGVmZ2MvVlB6R1phUmlINmtMMkU1SSs3MTZwOTFyUXB2aTlsa29FV0R2MHg1bGNuMyttVVZQL3FBay82RnptU29IK255OXdRVXlsN292aittdkZCRVJISWREdVhpaTdXWEtYRDhIVFBtRGxYUmRJL2lYaWtrMU16QzRZY1Rub2FMOFJPRjJnTmdzaW50T29tZm5xT3NGcjdFbTNyRUR1ZktDV0FWb05IVk5KNHFxeWw2R1M2RlBGQ2hTYVgxTDJ6SGlSR0pXaXhYRE8zay9IMC9BeG1HQTY5S2wzWUNEN0drdz09MVNFV2dFVStheXQ5YXVvWiJ9.G6z8gXvWYoUV_KZAnP8SqWwHMac0B7lnL1R8q9P28Tg?s=322e5e22-3542-4638-b621-fa06db098460
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200
```

The link contains the following form: https://hcaptcha.com/checkcaptcha /{solved captcha token}?s={site key}\

```
Request headers

:authority: hcaptcha.com
:method: POST
:path: /checkcaptcha/E0_eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJkYXRhIjoiUFBvbU0vUXJjVVpOenlHOENvSVlpOEVCK2RwSElDU1IrVlk5V1QxNXRTU3RwRWtkcGVmZ2MvVlB6R1phUmlINmtMMkU1SSs3MTZwOTFyUXB2aTlsa29FV0R2MHg1bGNuMyttVVZQL3FBay82RnptU29IK255OXdRVXlsN292aittdkZCRVJISWREdVhpaTdXWEtYRDhIVFBtRGxYUmRJL2lYaWtrMU16QzRZY1Rub2FMOFJPRjJnTmdzaW50T29tZm5xT3NGcjdFbTNyRUR1ZktDV0FWb05IVk5KNHFxeWw2R1M2RlBGQ2hTYVgxTDJ6SGlSR0pXaXhYRE8zay9IMC9BeG1HQTY5S2wzWUNEN0drdz09MVNFV2dFVStheXQ5YXVvWiJ9.G6z8gXvWYoUV_KZAnP8SqWwHMac0B7lnL1R8q9P28Tg?s=322e5e22-3542-4638-b621-fa06db098460
:scheme: https
accept: */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
content-length: 14908
content-type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
origin: https://newassets.hcaptcha.com
referer: https://newassets.hcaptcha.com/
sec-ch-ua: " Not;A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="97", "Chromium";v="97"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
sec-fetch-dest: empty
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: same-site
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.71 Safari/537.36
```

I tried to make the following request, but nothing has changed in selenium:

```
post = f'https://hcaptcha.com/checkcaptcha /{g_response}?s={site_key}'
requests.post(post)
```

I tried to describe the problem in as much detail as possible, tell me if you need to fix something / write in more detail. I understand that other data is needed for the post request, but I just have no idea what and from where to take them. I would be grateful if you write the code to solve the problem

Comment: please check this solution . https://stackoverflow.com/a/68886653/15462938